# Popularity algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

On SO 18 Joel mentioned an algorithm that would rank items based on their age and popularity and it's based on gravity.  Could someone post this? C# would be lovely, but really any language (well, I can't do LISP) would be fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My understanding is that it is approximately the following from another [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) post

```
t = (time of entry post) - (Dec 8, 2005)
x = upvotes - downvotes

y = {1 if x > 0, 0 if x = 0, -1 if x < 0)
z = {1 if x < 1, otherwise x}

log(z) + (y * t)/45000
```

Comment: I don't like this solution - why do we need to fix a certain date and have an ever growing t? Why not change it so that t is age, and rearrange the algorithm so that a lower score is better. Voila, now some random pulled date has no influence. (More principle than necessity, but hey, that's me :) )

Comment: If X=0 then y=0, then z=0, and you get log(0) :(

Comment: @Ofri Raviv - Good catch! - You are right, the Z formula should have been less than "1" not less than "0". A typo that has been there for about 11 months and you are the first to point it out! - Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

[alt text http://www.mt-soft.com.ar/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-o-matic/cache/0ad4d_reddit_cf_algorithm.png](http://www.mt-soft.com.ar/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-o-matic/cache/0ad4d_reddit_cf_algorithm.png)

Comment: @Ofri - I agree. The absolute value part of this is wrong I think. My answer (after fixing a typo you pointed out) is the intended answer.

Comment: Deadlink, answers like this shouldn't get upvoted without any piece of information in the answer besides an external link.