# Algorithm to determine thread "hotness"

Tags: algorithm, forum

I'm trying to come up with a way to determine how "hot" certain threads are in a forum. What criteria would you use and why? How would these come together to give a hotness score?

The criteria I'm thinking of include:

- how many replies
- how long since the last reply
- average time between replies

The problems this algorithm must solve:

- A thread which has 500 replies is clearly hot, unless the last reply was over a year ago.
- A thread with 500 replies that was replied to a second ago is clearly hot, unless it's taken 4 years to reach 500 replies.
- A thread with 15 replies in the last 4 minutes is really hot!

Any ideas, thoughts or complete solutions out there?

Comment: this might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397/popularity-algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Jeff Atwood has [a nice question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) about this with a ton of information on other "hot" algorithms. I suggest using one of those and adapting it to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest algorithm:
If there have been greater than X replies since Y, it is hot.

If you prefer something that scales, just count how many replies since time y.  More replies means more hotness.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking you could probably model it with diminishing waves here, using amplitude (or root mean square) to measure hotness.  As time goes, the wave diminishes, and so a late reply will only cause a little stir.

In practice, I think this requires a lot of calculation.  You could make good use of caching to speed up the calculation.

Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

In short I've found logarithmic decay of "hotness" to be the most natural.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who posted the links to the other questions/answers. Unfortunately, those equations take a lot more things into consideration than what's possible with my setup (eg: voting, reputation of author, etc)

After playing around with it, I've come up with this equation which I'll use for the time being:

```
log10($numOfReplies * 20000 / pow($timeSinceLastPost, 1.3))
```

It still could use some work. For example, if there's a really really popular but old thread, it'll be low on the hotness, but if one person replies to it that'll put it right back to the top for a few days/weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a sort of exponential decay model. Hotness of thread = sum( k^(time since posting) ) for all posts. This has the advantage of being really easy to update and calculate. You'd have to play around with k and your unit of time measurement (k should be < 1, but fairly close to it)

Current hotness = hotness at time of last post * k^(time since last post).
Hotness after new post = current hotness + 1

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should pay some attention to is whether people might want to "game" the algorithm in order to make/keep their threads "hot". Actually, you can pretty much assume that they will.

The minimum you should do to discourage this is to only consider replies from different people.