# StackOverflow's Popularity algorithm in MySQL

Tags: mysql, algorithm, math

How would you write SO's Popularity algorithm in MySQL?

The algorithm is detailed here: [Popularity algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397/popularity-algorithm).

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's relatively simple.

```
t = (time of entry post) - (Dec 8, 2005)
```

You would convert the date values to timestamps (you can use [`unix_timestamp`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)), which gives you an integer that can be used in the rest of the comparisons.

```
x = upvotes - downvotes
```

This one should be pretty easy... obviously MySQL supports subtraction.

```
y = {1 if x > 0, 0 if x = 0, -1 if x < 0)
z = {1 if x < 0, otherwise x}
```

For these, take a look at MySQL's [`case`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case-statement.html) statement.

```
log(z) + (y * t)/45000
```

MySQL has a [`log`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_log) function, so this one should be easy too, just simple math.

And, you tie it all together with a [`select`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) statement.  You can store intermediate calculations in your `select` statement using [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html).  For example:

```
select @x := (upvotes - downvotes) as x,
       (@x > 4) as isXGreaterThanFour
```

Comment: how do you use 'x' (upvotes-downvotes) in the CASE statement?

Comment: I added an example of how to use variables for intermediate calculations

Comment: Would you be able to write this out in it's entirety?  I'm still rather confused here...